# Alert when a partition is read/written

Tags: linux, filesystems, monitoring, io

My hard disk sometimes makes unexpected noise, indicating activity. By eyeballing `iotop` I believe this process is responsible:

```
mount.ntfs /dev/sda2 /storage -o rw,umask=007,gid=46
```

however the contents of `/storage` do not look like anything which I would expect any process to be accessing, and the `mnt.ntfs` process is owned by root, giving no information as to what is causing the disk access.

I want to find the (presumably) userspace processes which are causing this disk access. Can I attach some sort of monitor to `/dev/sda2` which will alert me with the PID of any process which causes `mount.ntfs` to do work?

Answer (score 3):

`mount.ntfs` is a FUSE "userspace filesystem" host – it actually *mounts a filesystem* at `/storage` and will access the disk whenever some other process wants to access the filesystem.

So, start by monitoring the filesystem – install the *fatrace* tool, and run:

```
# cd /storage
# sudo fatrace -c
```

(The `-c` option limits trace events to only the filesystem corresponding to the "current working directory".)

Every 'O'pen, 'R'ead, 'W'rite, or 'C'lose will be shown together with the corresponding PID and command name. (It uses the fanotify API, which is somewhat similar to inotify, but system-wide instead of per-directory.)

Comment: `cd /storage` then `sudo fatrace -c` gives `fatrace: Failed to add watch for .: No such device`